# rails - how to dynamically add/override wording to i18n yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

as an example, i have a default english locale file "en.yml" with contents:

```
 en:
  messages: messages
  users: users
```

now, there is a customer which wants messages to be named discussions in his product, but users should remain users. so what i want to do is to create "customer.en.yml" file

```
en:
 messages: discussions
```

which would override the default "messages" translation, but would keep all the other words same. how can i achieve it?

because if i load en.yml with :

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

and afterwards load customer.en.yml (APP_CONFIG['customer_name'] is defined before) with

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'custom_locales',  APP_CONFIG['customer_name']+'.{rb|yml}')]
```

it will just overwrite my "en" locale, and "users" translation will disappear, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not overwrite your "en" locale. Translations are merged. `store_translations` in the simple I18n backend calls `merge_translations`, which looks like this:

```
# Deep merges the given translations hash with the existing translations
# for the given locale
def merge_translations(locale, data)
  locale = locale.to_sym
  translations[locale] ||= {}
  data = deep_symbolize_keys(data)

  # deep_merge by Stefan Rusterholz, see http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/142809
  merger = proc { |key, v1, v2| Hash === v1 && Hash === v2 ? v1.merge(v2, &merger) : v2 }
  translations[locale].merge!(data, &merger)
end
```

As you can see, only the keys you enter in the latter translation yml file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 7):

## Use i18n.fallbacks

I'm not sure when this was added to Rails, but in 4.2.2 you can do:

```
# application.rb
# If key is not found in a locale, we look in fallback
config.i18n.fallbacks = {
  "locale_1"    => "en",
  "locale_2"    => "en",
  "locale_3"    => "de",
}
```

If you also set `config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true` (which I do in development and test), it will raise only if a key isn't found in the locale **or** the fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar when we were writing a pirate.yml translation, but I wanted anything not defined in pirate.yml to default to what we had in en.yml.

What I wrote can be found on [Github](http://github.com/amiel/i18n_with_default).

Comment: Github link is not valid anymore!

Comment: Not valid? While it is a very old project, the link still works for me. Are you getting a 404?

Comment: Exactly a `page not found` is what I'm getting!

Comment: @YanFoto weird, the link still works for me (even when logged out). Could it be an https issue? Are you in need of the code? I could gist it for you. I'm not sure how else I can help...

Comment: The link works when I copy/paste it and not when clicking on it! Mysterious... But I have already found a workaround for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think you might be mixing up two different things.

The i18n file is for translations.

If you have a client that needs an specific name for some field, that is not a translation issue, but functionality.

In other words, I think you need something like this:

```
 en:
   messages: messages
   users: users
   discussions: discussions
```

And then add the specific functionality somewhere else, for example in your view:

```
if(customer.needs_discussions?)
<%= t(:discussions) %>
else
<%= t(:messages) %>
end
```

Alternatively, you could add a string attribute to your customers, defaulting to 'messages'. Then your view would look like this:

```
<%= t(customer.messages_field_name) %>
```

Comment: well,then if he needs 200 changes in wording, i have to write 200 ifs and add 200 customer settings, and same for each other customer using product his own way. this would heavily increase amount of code. and, if the specific customer leaves at, all those ifs would stay in the code, while otherwise i simply delete translation override.

Comment: The code was just an example - what I meant is that you shouldn't be using i18n for that. I've edited my comment with other solutions. If you continue thinking about using i18n, think about what will happen when you have to translate your application to french, for instance.

Comment: i already have french and english i18n, and on top of them i load customer overrides. i have locales/en.yml, locales/fr.yml and on top of them i load locales/customer.en.yml and locales/customer.fr.yml, if needed. i am sorry, but i really think that this way is way better for simple wording customizations